# Tensorflow works in Python terminal but neither in notebook jupyter nor in Ipython

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, ipython

I follow [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows) tutorial to install tensorflow in my windows 7, I adopte the conda proposetion: `conda create -n tensorflow python=3.5` , when I imported the library in python it worked but when I did the same thing with notebook and Ipython I got this error:

```
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

even when I restart the Kernel I got the same Error.

UPDATE:

When I run the command `os.environ` in the both windows I can notice that they don't have the same contain (notebook doesn't contain the Tensorflow environment variable)

Comment: Did you `activate` the environment you created and install TensorFlow in that?

Comment: You could try using anaconda (https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/install/index.html) it installs tensorflow and jupyter all together without the need to manually install it

Comment: @fuglede How can i do that??

Comment: @hisi: Cf. point 3 in the guide you referred to, through `activate tensorflow`.

Comment: @fuglede I did it in the commande Line as they mentioned, but not in jupyter

Comment: @hisi: In Jupyter, you would then select the kernel named `tensorflow` from the dropdown, or via "Kernel -> Change kernel". If you were running Jupyter before you installed TensorFlow, you might have to restart it. If, however, you are running IPython from the `tensorflow` conda environment, then it should work there as well.

Answer (score 0):

`conda create -n tensorflow python=3.5`

Here `-n tensorflow` means you are creating a new environment named tensorflow, there is no tensorflow library installed there yet. Run `activate tensorflow` to activate this environment, then `conda install tensorflow` or `pip install tensorflow`.

Edit: If you did that, then either you must run `jupyter notebook` after you have `activate`d your environment or choose the kernel manually in jupyter.

Comment: yes I did it by: (tensorflow)C:> pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow. But still not working in notebook

Comment: I see, I try to fix the issue with it

Answer (score 0):

You may be running ipython from a different environment. Try installing ipython-notebook into your conda environment (after you have activated it):

`conda install ipython-notebook`

Even then, on OSX I see that my system wide installation of ipython seems to be before in my path so I start it by giving the explicit path:

`$CONDA_ENV_PATH/bin/ipython notebook`

(I guess the equivalent on Windows starts with `%CONDA_ENV_PATH%\`)

Answer (score 0):

Which vertion of anaconda do you use?
you can try

```
conda install nb_conda
```

it is a plug-in.Then you can start jupyter notebook and see different environment when create new notebook page.

Above all, you should understand anaconda environment(python version and related lib,module) first,it helps a lot.